# Firebase events with no delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Is it a good idea to use [Firebase events](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html) api to sync something between clients in real time?

For example, if I want to play video on clients exactly at the same time (with delays less than 30ms), can I rely on Firebase here? Is there any way to use Firebase to start events synced as much as it possible on both clients? (assuming clients are looking at the same page in the browser).

I tried to play with it, and it seems pretty reliable, but I'm not sure it is the right approach.

Another way of doing that is just to exchange the packet saying: "Starting at XXX UTC", where XXX is the time of now + 1000ms (for example). For one client packet transmission can take 40ms, for another 900ms. But this event will be synced. But the question here is how to know that client time is set up correctly?

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, and wanna check if you guys had this experience before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a client connects to the Firebase Database back-end, the Firebase SDK detects the latency of that client. Local time-based operations (such as `push()` and `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`) are automatically corrected for that detected latency. You can also [listen for the latency on `.info/serverTimeOffset`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#clock-skew).

With that you can get Firebase's best estimate of how in-sync the clients are. Whether that is enough to synchronize video playback for your needs is anyone's guess. I'd love to hear some numbers if you start testing it though.

Comment: Hi Frank what is the average latency for Firebase? We're having some trouble with real-time movement in a game (sometimes smooth, but jerky because updates from other users seem delayed), and wondering if it's something we're doing wrong with FB (wrong setting, wrong event to monitor, etc) or if FB isn't suited for this.

Comment: Latency depends on where you are in the world, what type of connection you're on, how many other users are active, etc. Those are facts-of-life on the internet, not specific to Firebase. Since they are uncontrollable, most game developers design their game to work within these known parameters.

Comment: Yup, understood. Sorry for the ambiguity. We tested on two devices connected to same Wi-Fi (in Bay Area), but saw spotty real-time performance so wondering if we misconfigured/misused FB or if it's not meant to support < 50 ms performance even with good networking conditions. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: And to clarify, here's the example: https://mmoasteroids.firebaseapp.com/. This performance is great. Are we doing something wrong with Firebase, or is this demo not representative?

Comment: I'm surprised that demo is still active. :-) The demo runs on the exact same (type of) hardware as all other Firebase databases. If you're having problems, post a new question with the [minimal complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).